# SQL join and filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, where-clause, temp-tables

Does these two solutions give the same result ?

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN OrderLines ON OrderLines.OrderID=Orders.ID 
    AND Orders.ID = 12345
```

---

```
select orderID
into #temp
from OrderLines
where orderID=12345

SELECT *
    FROM Orders
    LEFT JOIN #temp t ON t.OrderID=Orders.ID
```

I would like to use the temp tables for performance

Comment: Tell us why you think they do or don't or ask about where you are stuck determining that while reading documentation. You are just asking us to rewrite it, while not knowing why you are stuck. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN OrderLines ON OrderLines.OrderID=Orders.ID 
    AND Orders.ID = 12345
```

This query will give you

- All the records from the `Orders` table
- Matching records from `OrderLines` table for only Orders with `ID = 12345` for all other Orders you will find OrderLines Null.

--

```
select orderID
into #temp
from OrderLines
where orderID=12345

SELECT *
    FROM Orders
    LEFT JOIN #temp t ON t.OrderID=Orders.ID
```

Let's consider your first query where You are fetching only those records from `OrderLines` where `OrderId = 12345` and then Joining it with the `Orders` table. so Your query output will be

- All the records from the `Orders` table
- For OrderID 12345, OrderLines will be available and for all others, `Orderlines` will be null

So Yes, **Both the query will give you the same output**.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use the temp tables for performance

My basic reaction is:  get over it.  Temporary tables can be useful in some cases, particularly when a script is running multiple queries and need to share a certain subquery.  However, they incur overhead in creating the table, loading it with data, and then reading it again.  That can be a lot of overhead.

In general, though, lots of effort has gone into developing databases and their optimizers.  You can usually trust the optimizer to do the right thing.  There is no need to try to outwit the optimizer.

Sometimes, the optimizer is not perfect.  Most database support some use of hints to produce a more suitable query plan.  Under some circumstances, you might find that creating a temporary table with the appropriate indexes produces a better query plan.

Your first query is going to be faster than your second query under most circumstances.  If it is not, the statistics on the `OrderLines` are probably out of date.